# How to control the position of floating images?

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

I want to make it like this:

```
text
image
text
image
```

But even if I put `[h!]` to the position the figures, the figure is moved to the next page because it is too large. The text which should be under the figure goes up over it!!!

How I can fix it?

Comment: You can simply use `[H]`, this forces the figure to be placed exactly `H`ere. Or even better, don't use a float environment at all if you don't want the figure to float.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can use `\FloatBarrier` from the [placeins](https://ctan.org/pkg/placeins) package to prevent floats (figures) pass some point such as start of the text that follows. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics{pic1.jpg}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
Text
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics{pic2.jpg}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
Text
\end{document}
```