# Image placing problems in LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I've trouble with placing images in LaTeX. I know that is a starter problem.

In my document (research) I have a lot of graphs (40 graphs on 20 pages). So LaTeX just throw all images in all directions and the text in another direction. So I have some text clustert on some pages, and just a huge among of images on another one. So actually there are some text with the corresponding image like four pages beneath.

Is there any method to make LaTeX place the images correctly? So there is an image and then some text and than the next image? Like how I wrote it in my Tex-Document?

It doesn't matter if LaTeX just make a pagebreak and let some free space on sites, so that the text and images are in the right order. And `\pagebreak` doesn't help, LaTeX doesn't make anything. And it would actually be nice, if I not have to write `\pagebreak` all the time, but when LaTeX would do it for me.

Could you please make a suggestion for a one columnd and a twocolumn document? I write in documentclass `article`.

PS! I think a lot of us who are new to LaTeX have the same problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/35864), [Force figure placement in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625/35864), [How to fix table position](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9485/35864), [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/35864), [How to control the position of floating images?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19766/35864).

Comment: although the pointers by @moewe to other questions are all good, it sounds to me that you really shouldn't be using floating tables if it is important that the associated text is in a particular arrangement with respect to the tables.  this answer addresses that situation explicitly: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631

Comment: latex only moves images if you specify that they can be moved by wrapping them in `\begin{figure}` If you use `\includegraphics{zzz}` then it is positioned exactly like `zzz` and will move or not in the same way as tEx breaks lines and pages.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the link @barbarabeeton gave. Do you agree?

Comment: Although for you doesn't matter if LaTeX left big free spaces because a forced image positions, for a lot of images and little text  in general would be better give to each float the greatest possible freedom with  `\begin{figure}[!htbp] \caption{xxx}\label{yyy}...` , make cross-references in text with `\ref{yyy}`,and only if needed in the final version,  make a fine tuning of the float options.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the float environment, [thanks to Juan A. Navarro answered Jan 10 '11 at 12:01](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8633/79690):

```
\usepackage{float}

\begin{figure}[H]
...
```

Or if you not want to use the float environment: [thanks to Herbert, answered Jan 10 '11 at 11:57](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/79690):

```
\usepackage{caption}
...
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% to keep image and caption on one page
\makebox[\linewidth]{%        to center the image
  \includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,scale=0.6]{slike/visina8}}
\captionof{figure}{...}\label{visina8}%      only if needed  
\end{minipage}
```