# Manually Place a Figure in LaTeX (here: End of Chapter/Section)

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a little problem with the placement of my picture. I want to insert it at the end of the introduction chapter but its place is not where I want.

I think the problem become from the:

```
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
```

Because when I insert the picture without using `\begin{figure}...` the picture is at the end of the chapter as I want.

Look the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Does `\begin{figure}[b]...` help? Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Did you see the posting [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5001)? A separate question: Why did you set the tag "table of contents"?

Comment: BTW do your self a favour an unlearn using ``\\`` in the text, all those **underfull vbox baddness 10000** are because of the ``\\`` we can see from your code image. There is no need to have spaces between paragraphs when you also have paragraph indentation, it makes the text look less professional.

Comment: Another option is `\floatbarrier` from `placeins`: More details: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19767/28808

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Exact/Manual Placing/Positioning of Figures/Pictures/Tables/"Normally Floating Objects" in LaTeX by Using the `float` Package

---

- The `float` package provides the `H` placement option.
- `H` places a figure (float) exactly where you put it in the code.
- The remaining code is the same as for normal figures (floats).
- **Warning:** Many very experienced users here seem to dislike this solution for some reason whereas I still like it because the code is the same for floating and non-floating objects.
- Normally one is supposed to let LaTeX decide where to place a figure (for a nicer layout).
- I found myself often in a situation (e. g. supervisor wishes a specific position) where I was happy that the `float` package offers a manual approach.
- Highley related questions: [Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625) and [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017) (provided in a comment above).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[H] % <-- Use [H] for exactly here
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{I am a caption.}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zarko :) -- I am really trying to avoid a discussion here. If it helps the OP then I am happy. Open a chat if that's not enough for you (I am on the computer for the next hour).

Comment: It works I just did the changes thanks a lot my friend ! :) Sorry for the late ^^