# Text placed under figure instead of above

Tags: positioning

I have a figure that contains two subfigures side by side:

```
Foobar

\begin{figure*}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=5.0in]{ressourcen/market_category}
        \caption{Market category cocktails}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=5.0in]{ressourcen/market_category_2}
        \caption{Market category lemonade}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Market dashboard}
\end{figure*}
```

However the text `foobar` is placed under the figure instead of above it. I want to control the placement with `h!` but it has no effect. Any ideas how to have the text above the figure?

Comment: That depends on the context. LaTeX tries to place floats in the best possible way according to its criteria.

Comment: B.t.w. are you in two-column mode?

Comment: @Bernard nope, not two-column mode

Comment: IIRC, [h!] is actually translated as [htp], which is far more reasonable but the opposite of what you would expect.

Comment: As a last resort, you can use the `[H]` float placement from the `float` package, but it may result in unwanted blank areas in your document. Another solution would be the  `\insertBoxC` plain TeX macro (load the package with `\input{insbox}`).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375068. This is a common request :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- See [Manually Place a Figure in LaTeX (here: End of Chapter/Section)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375068) for details.
- I use `figure` instead of `figure*`.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


Text before.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.0in]{example-image}
        \caption{Market category cocktails}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.0in]{example-image}
        \caption{Market category lemonade}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Market dashboard}
\end{figure}

Text after.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't work with 'figure*'... And I think @zab had a reason to use it

Comment: Maybe. He doesn't say something about it. Otherwise the answer may help others with a similar problem.

Comment: Yes... of course... And it is more used method...(I thought I used 'float' package too but I did not) I just said what I said because it is not a duplicate...

Comment: Ok :). Going to bed now.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner actually there is no special reason I use figure*, I removed the * and and now it's working

Answer (score 1):

Try with `[ht!]` parameter.

(Also you may want to use 'keepaspectratio' in 'includegraphics' because you may loose the format of the figure if not)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


Foobar

\begin{figure*}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.0in]{Sc1.png}
        \caption{Market category cocktails}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.0in]{Sc2.png}
        \caption{Market category lemonade}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Market dashboard}
\end{figure*}
%\ref{test}

\end{document}
```

This is my code and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Steven B. Segletes... I didn't know that we write packages and parameters in quotes

Comment: It is a matter of taste perhaps, but the rule of thumb I use is that if it is text that would be typed directly in a tex document, I use backquote delimiters to set it as `code`.

Comment: Thank you, however ht! makes no difference, the problem remains

Comment: @zab, probably something else is wrong with your packages or your macros in the documentclass or somewhere...  take a look to my MWE... it works for me

Comment: @koleygr: I love your cocktails :o)

Comment: @Bernard the photo of my profile is "stolen"... be quiet because I love it too.... I hope that the owner (the dog) will not sue me!

Comment: I think you mean [H] in combination with the float package.

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner.... you are right that it was my mistake... but not 'H'... it doesn't work.... I mean just '[ht!]' without the float.... sorry... I thought float needed there... Editing...

Comment: I think that https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375068 is also relevant in this context.

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner I tried float options on my MWE and the figures does not show on the pdf... Something doesn't work with float and alligned photos...

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60988/discussion-between-koleygr-and-dr-manuel-kuehner).