# Multiple floats that clearly fit on one page, are spread out on two pages

Tags: floats

I have a weird layout problem in LaTeX, in which, for some reason, floats that can *clearly* fit on one page, are spread out on two pages, even when using big vspaces.

[image: Layout problem]

The attached picture shows the compiled result of the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.85\textwidth]{baseline_sensor2}
\caption{Test ID S2.1 - sensor 2}
\end{figure}

\vspace{-5cm}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.85\textwidth]{baseline_sensor3}
\caption{Test ID S2.1 - sensor 3}
\end{figure}
```

I've had this problem on several occasions with this template. Weirdly enough, if I do manage to reduce the size sufficiently to gather the floats on one page, I can still add some text on that same page, without messing up the layout. Even when the size reduction is 1 % different from what doesn't fit on the page.

This is my preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{report}

%% Formatting %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel} %francais, polish, spanish, ...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} %Type1-font for non-english texts and characters

%% Packages for Graphics & Figures %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx} %%For loading graphic files
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[headheight=70pt,margin=1.0in,top=1.5in,bottom=1.0in,showframe=false]{geometry}

%% Packages for tables:
\usepackage{tabularx} % Include for better table functionality
\usepackage{tablefootnote} % Include to allow for footnotes in tables
\usepackage{multirow} % Write one entry for multiple rows and columns in tables
\usepackage{booktabs} % Insert divider rules in tables

%% Color Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.4mm} % witdh of lines
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt} % width of each row
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0,0.59765625,0.59765625}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{0.6875,0.08984375,0.12109375}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0.25390625,0.41015625,0.87890625} 
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.9140625,0.9140625,0.9453125}
\definecolor{gray2}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
\definecolor{stoneblack}{rgb}{0.234375  ,  0.2734375 ,  0.29296875}
\definecolor{snow}{rgb}{0.99609375  ,  0.99609375 ,  0.99609375}
\definecolor{sgreen}{rgb}{0,0.59765625,0.59765625}
\definecolor{stonelight}{rgb}{0.67578125,0.7421875,0.79296875}
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{0.99609375,  0.72265625,  0}
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0  ,  0 ,  0}
\definecolor{red2}{rgb}{0.68359375,  0.13671875,  0.37109375}

%% Math Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{siunitx} % Allows for easy unit input

%% Line Spacing %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing        %% 1-spacing (default)
%\onehalfspacing       %% 1,5-spacing
%\doublespacing        %% 2-spacing

%% Other Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref} % Allows for inserting urls with \url{}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{depth=3} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} % Used for textblock on frontpage
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage} % Included so that \LastPage can be used to get pagenumber for last page
\usepackage{titlesec} % Include to control chapter and section display
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % Included to be able to make colored, rounded textboxes


%% My commands %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\todo[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1}}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{0.5em}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-15pt}{10pt}
```

Sorry for the big code-snippet, but I am clueless as to where it goes wrong.

Comment: Well, you say `\begin{figure}[ht]`, which means "here or on top". Try changing it to `[htp]`, which adds the option to place the figure on a floats-only page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but just tried it out, and it doesn't work.

Comment: As a last resort you can always **position** the figure(s) **manually**: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375068

Comment: Eurika! The package "float" combined with [H] as a placement option does exactly what I want! Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

The default, and often the best, location for floats is `[tbp]` (top, bottom, page). There are macros you can use to change how a float may be located on a page. These, together with the default value in parentheses, are

Change these with `\setcounter`:

`topnumber` (2) max number of floats at top of page

`bottomnumber` (1) max number of floats at bottom of page

`totalnumber` (3) max number of floats on a text page

`dbltopnumber` (2) like `topnumber` for double column floats

Change the following with `\renewcommand`:

`\topfraction` (0.7) max fraction of page reserved for top floats

`\bottomfraction` (0.3) max fraction of page for bottom floats

`\textfraction` (0.2) min fraction of page that must have text

`\dbltopfraction` (0.7) like `\topfraction` for double column floats

`\floatpagefraction` (0.5) min fraction of a float page that must have float(s)

`\dblfloatpagefraction` (0.5) like `\floatpagefraction` for double column floats

There are also macros for controlling the spacing around floats.

The `memoir` class documentation (`< texdoc memoir`) gives more details in its section *10.4 Where LaTeX puts floats*.

Adjust the above parameters until you get the layout that suits you.

Comment: For completeness, an example syntax would be `\setcounter{bottomnumber}{2}` or `\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.5}`