# Table keeps having error "a <box> was supposed to be here"

Tags: tables, errors, boxes

Everytime I set a table's position to [H], an error appears saying "A `<box>` was supposed to be here". The table fits the page and everything appears to be fine, except for the errors. If I change the position of the table the error disappeares but I want the table exactly at that place.

My table code is like this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Types of accounts and their permissions}
\label{table:accounts}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
 %content
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please post a full minimal example instead of just a sniplet. The preamble matters in situations like this. (3) You really should not use `[H]`, rather learn to use floats correctly.

Comment: Thanks @daleif
I tried to look for ways to avoid [H] when I want the table exactly at that position, and found that using [h!] together with`\FloatBarrier` from the placeins package works just fine and the box error disappears. It is explained here [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19767/139067]

Comment: There is no reason for the code you show to make a box error, so please add some more code to reproduce the problem. (Noting in the placeins package should make such an error go) also never use `[!h]` it usually generates a warning that it is being changed. better to use `[htp]`