# How to assign two floats on the same page but not a one-top-one-bottom style

Tags: floats

I have some texts before and after two floats. The order is:

```
Text A....
Float B
Another float C
Text D....
```

If A and B can not be placed on one page, B and C will be put on next place. In this case D will be inserted between B and C and the order will be:

```
Page 1
  Text A....
  A portion of text D....

Page 2
  Float B
  A portion of text D....
  Another float C
```

But I want to get the following order:

```
Page 1
  Text A....
  A portion of text D....

Page 2
  Float B
  Another float C
  A portion of text D....
```

When I use 'h', 'ht', or 'htb' option for the floats, I cann't get the desired result. How can I achieve this?

Note: B and C are two seperate floats and I don't want to bind them together, because I allow B and C be splitted on two pages.

Comment: Put `B` an `C` in the *same* `figure` environment.

Comment: Having a float at the bottom is common, an what floating means. Don't bother about the positioning. LaTeX already does.

Comment: What about use `t` only in the second float, without `h`? It could be that it is allowed only one top float per page in your unknown document class or preamble, but that is not the default a standard document class.

Comment: saying that you have text before and after a float is already a sign of a problem. The _only_ reason to mark anything with a float environment such as `figure` or `table` is to take it out of the document flow and specify that it may be inserted at some place convenient for page breaking so  you have specified `Text A` and  `Text D` follow each other in the main document flow, and separately specified to floating insertions that may be inserted at some point close, depending on page breaking requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\FloatBarrier` from the placeins package to prevent floats (figures) pass some point such as start of the text that follows.

See also: [[How to control the position of floating images?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19766/how-to-control-the-position-of-floating-images][1])