# How to prevent figures from appearing at the top of a page?

Tags: graphics, floats, include, includegraphics, subfig

Why is it that, when I insert my figure with `\begin{figure}`, it is placed at the beginning of the paper ?
[image]

Comment: Take a look at those similar questions : [original](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned) , [duplicate with simple answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19766/how-to-control-the-position-of-floating-images).

Comment: The _only_ purpose of using the `figure`  environment is to allow the figure to be moved to help with page breaking.

Comment: For a really good read about LaTeX's floats: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/117050

Comment: @DavidCarlisle could you elaborate ?

Comment: `\includegraphics` includes the image. You haven't shown any code but presumably you wrapped it in `\begin{figure}..\end{figure}` that environment doesn't do anything to do with including images, it just marks the region as a float that can be moved and re-inserted at another place to help with page breaking.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify `[H]` like the code below

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{image.png}
    \caption{Caption.}
    \label{fig:image1}
\end{figure}
```

Add `\usepackage{float}`

Comment: You should mention that by default `[H]` will give an error `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`H'.`

Comment: Your answer is misleading. In the case, that ina document preamble you load package `float` (which define `H`), figure can still appear at the top of page (for example, if on the page is not enough space for figure, it is pushed to the next page and left empty space on the previous).

Answer (score 0):

So, the way i fixed this was by using `center` instead of `figure`:

```
\begin{center}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{image.png}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{fig:image1}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Using `center` and `\centering` is redundant

Comment: What happens with the `\caption`? Does it still print correctly as a figure caption?

Comment: Thank you  mayba can help another