# How to make section (appendix) name appear before floats

Tags: floats, appendices

I have an external file containing figures.

I want to import this file as appendix, the latex (pseudo-)code is below

```
    \appendix
        \clearpage
        \section{Appendix_name}
        \import{dir_name}{external_file_name}
```

My problem is that floats are pushed to the top of the page, and the Appendix name comes in the bottom of the first appendix page.

[I'm struggling to decide what MWE code to provide]

Figures take 3 full pages. On the image, in the first page I have depicted Section name by the single line.

Current (automatic) float placement

[image: current layout]

Required (or more appropriate)

[image: wanted layout]

The file is automatically created from (some class) code, so I'm interested to keep it that way. It could be inserted to other documents, therefore I'm reluctant to add all those [b] or [h!] specifiers to figures (and I'm not sure these specifiers ensure the placement).

The section does not contain any text - only those figures.

Comment: If you don't want your images to float don't use the `figure` environment. To insert an image exactly where is was mentioned in the code, use a simple `\includegraphics` command. If you need a caption for such an image, use the `\captionof{figure}{...}` command from the caption pakage.

Comment: Maybe you need a `\FloatBarrier` (from `placeins` package) patched to `\appendix`. See [How to control the position of floating images?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19767).

Comment: In the end, I have dropped the figures and pushed everything into minipages.